# How can I use built-in function to find the closest value in list to a target?

Tags: python

E.g., given

```
from collections import namedtuple
Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
points = [Point(x=1.0, y=1.0), Point(x=2.0, y=2.0), Point(x=5.0, y=5.0)] 
target = Point(x=4.5, y=5.0)
closest_point = find_closest(target, points)
```

I want to return `Point(x=5.0, y=5.0)`. Ideally I'd like to use a built in function that takes `(list, target, comp)` where `comp` takes `(a, b) -> float` and the goal is to find such `a` from `list` that minimizes `(a, target)`, e.g.:

```
closest_point = find_closest(points, target, dist) # where dist is (a.x-b.x)**2 + (a.y-b.y)**2
```

The reason I'm interested in this is because I found myself writing 3 duplicated functions where the only difference is that `dist` functions (and they use different fields to compute it).

Comment: Use [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) with a custom key.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog could you give me the code pointer?

Comment: Have a go first yourself, and come back if you are still stuck.

Comment: `bisect.bisect` can help with this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `min` function can take a `key` argument, which is a function to use as your comparator. In this case you can write a `lambda` to compute the distance from each point to `target`.

```
>>> min(points, key=lambda pt : sqrt((target.x - pt.x)**2 + (target.y - pt.y)**2))
Point(x=5.0, y=5.0)
```

Comment: Small optimization: the `sqrt` is unnecessary.

Comment: Just a note that you don't need the sqrt calculation here. the smallest sqrt will also be the smallest square.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following example code:

```
def find_closest(target, points):
    dist = []
    for i in points:
        dist.append((i.x - target.x)**2 + (i.y - target.y)**2)
    min_index = dist.index(min(dist))      
    return points[min_index]


closest_point = find_closest(target, points)
```

It gives output: `Point(x=5.0, y=5.0)`